# How to flatten PDF form, while still keep the button intact?

Tags: pdfbox

I have flatten pdf form using PDFBOX acroForm.flatten(). but using this method it will remove the button.

I still want the button to work even after I flatten my pdf.
[This the pdf i want to flatten](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BuQS91g5N61qZ8ASuAJkeaO4D4VwjgE7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: did you try the flatten() method with parameters? And why would you keep the button only? Did doesn't really make sense if you have nothing to submit.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr thank you. yes using flatten() with parameters work.. btw the reason why I wanna keep button because pdf form image field is a PDPushButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use flatten with parameters:

```
public void flatten(List<PDField> fields, boolean refreshAppearances)
```

this will only flatten the fields you want.